# python ElementTree.Element missing text?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

So, I'm parsing this xml file of moderate size (about 27K lines).  Not far into it, I'm seeing unexpected behavior from ElementTree.Element where I get Element.text for one entry but not the next, yet it's there in the source XML as you can see:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:enumeration value="24">
   <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>UPC12 (item-specific) on cover 2</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation>AKA item/price; ‘cover 2’ is defined as the inside front cover of a book</xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="25">
   <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>UPC12+5 (item-specific) on cover 2</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation>AKA item/price; ‘cover 2’ is defined as the inside front cover of a book</xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
```

When I encounter an *enumeration* tag I call this function:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
...
    def _parse_list_item(xmlns: str, list_id: int, itemElement: ElementTree.Element) -> ListItem:
      if isinstance(itemElement, ElementTree.Element):
        if itemElement.attrib['value'] is not None:
            item_id = itemElement.attrib['value']  # string
            if list_id == 6 and (item_id == '25' or item_id=='24'):
                print(list_id, item_id)  # <== debug break point here
            desc = None
            notes = ""
            for child in itemElement:
                if child.tag == (xmlns + 'annotation'):
                    for grandchild in child:
                        if grandchild.tag == (xmlns + 'documentation'):
                            if desc is None:
                                desc = grandchild.text
                            else:
                                if len(notes)>0:
                                    notes += " "  # add a space
                                notes += grandchild.text or ""
            if item_id is not None and desc is not None:
                return Codex.ListItem({'itemId': item_id, 'listId': list_id, 'description': desc, 'notes': notes})
```

If I place a breakpoint at the print statement, when I get to the enumeration node for "24" I can look at the text for the grandchild nodes and they are as shown in the XML, i.e. "UPC12..." or "AKA item...", but when I get to the enumeration node for "25", and look at the grandchild text, it's None.

When I remove the xs: namespace by pre-filtering the XML file, the grandchild text comes through fine.

Is it possible I'm over some size limit or is there some syntax problem?
Sorry for less-than-pythonic code but I wanted to be able to examine all the intermediate values in pycharm.  It's python 3.6.

Thanks for any insights you may have!

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop, this condition is never met: `if child.tag == (xmlns + 'annotation'):`.

Why?

Try to output the child's tag. If we suppose your namespace (xmlns) is '`Steve`' then:

`print(child.tag)` will output: `{Steve}annotation`, not `Steveannotation`.

So given this fact, `if child.tag == (xmlns + 'annotation'):` is always `False`.
You should change it to: `if child.tag == ('{'+xmlns+'}annotation'):`

With the same logic, you will find out you will also have to change this condition:

```
if grandchild.tag == (xmlns + 'documentation'):
```

to:

```
if grandchild.tag == ('{'+xmlns+'}documentation'):
```

Comment: Sorry, I see a bit more information is needed.  The XML file contains this line near the top: <pre>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</pre>
And so before I call into this function, I've parsed this line and set xmlns to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema} so when we come across child.tag = '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}annotation' then xmlns+'annotation' does match...  

I am considering removing the prefixes from the tags with pre-process if that's what's throwing me off.

Comment: @SteveL: the information in the comment should be part of the question. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn - thanks - info moved from comment to main body of question.

Comment: @SteveL: OK, but I still cannot copy and paste the code and just run it. You have not provided a **minimal but complete** piece of code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, ultimately, I solved my problem by running a pre-process on the XML file to remove the xs: namespace from all of the open/close XML tags and then I was able to successfully process the file using the function as defined above.  Not sure why namespaces are causing problems, but perhaps there is a bug in cElementTree for namespace prefixes in large XML files.  To @mzjn - I expect that it would be difficult to construct a minimal example as it does process hundreds of items correctly before it fails, so I would at least have to provide a fairly large XML file. Nevertheless, thanks for being a sounding board.